# Arching Java Graphics 2D text using while preserving vertical characters

Tags: java, text, graphics

I'm looking for ideas how a text string drawn on a Graphics 2D Canvas can be arched or warped but still retain each character's vertical orientation.

Here is a discussion how to do it in PhotoShop for reference.
https://forums.adobe.com/thread/2390526

Example of vertical arched text:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/q0Yog.png]

Comment: I've never attempted this before, but at first glance, I think you should look at AffineTransform. It seems to be able to handle what you need: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/advanced/transforming.html